# Flattening the two different JSON array in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with the JSON data as follows.

```
|---------------|
|    JSON_DATA  | 
|———————————————|
|     JSON_1    |
|     JSON_2    |
|---------------|
```

JSON_1 Consists the data as follows

```
{
    "Money_Earned" : [
        {
           "money" :  2
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON_2 Consists the data as follows

```
{
    "Money_Spent" : [
        {
           "money" :  3
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my SQL code to retrieve the data from the above table, I'm flattening the JSON array

```
SELECT v.value:money as money_earned,
        v2.value:money as money_spent
FROM TABLE, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => JSON_DATA: Money_Earned) v, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => JSON_DATA: Money_Spent) v2
```

I want the table to be

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|     MONEY_EARNED       |      MONEY_SPENT       | 
|------------------------|------------------------|
|          2             |           0            | <== money_spent 0 because there is not money_spent in JSON_1
|          0             |           3            | <== money_earned 0 because there is not money_earned in JSON_2
|-------------------------------------------------|
```

But I’m getting some other table when I was using the above SQL code. I don’t understand where I’m doing wrong

Comment: Hi - I assume JSON_1 and JSON_2 are different rows in your table?

Comment: @NickW Yes, those two are two different rows

Comment: The JSON strings in the question are not valid JSON strings. Can you replace them for something that parses correctly?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I modified the JSON strings

Comment: Cool - now, if those arrays of moneys had more than one value (because arrays), how would you aggregate that?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I need not aggregate them. I need all the values in thatJSON array

Answer (score 0):

Your "money" is a JSON array with a single member. If it's always a single member, you can do this (using table name FOO and column name JSON_DATA):

```
select    zeroifnull(JSON_DATA:Money_Earned[0].money) as MONEY_EARNED,
          zeroifnull(JSON_DATA:Money_Spent[0].money) as MONEY_SPENT
from foo;
```

I used a table that looks like this. If your actual data is more complex, please post a sample:

```
create temp table foo(JSON_DATA variant);
insert into foo select parse_json('{"Money_Earned":[{"money":2}]}');
insert into foo select parse_json('{"Money_Spent":[{"money":3}]}');
insert into foo select parse_json('{"Money_Earned":[{"money":6}], "Money_Spent":[{"money":7}]}');
```

Comment: The JSON array is not a single member. In some of the JSON data both ```Money_Earned``` and ```Money_Spent``` are present together

Comment: The sample will still work as long as there's only one "money" in the array. I updated the sample to show that. If you have more than one money in the array it will have to be handled differently.